# SVG text position is too varry from chrome vs firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I have below code to draw the svg text.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Center text in SVG rect -- horz and vert</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg height="50" width="200">
  <rect fill="green" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="50"></rect>
  <text x="100" y="25" fill="red" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central">Christmas Time!</text>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

it was working fine in chrome alone.(svg text y location)
The out put is totally different in firefox and IE? how to resolve this?